# Python program question snake game, box making using, random fun

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to python. I tried to make a python snake game and I got a problem with making a small rectangle on the screen which should appear on screen every time I run the program. But the rectangle is moving very fast I don't know why. just tell me how to code so that the rectangle stays in one place and changes position every time I run the program

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.math import Vector2
import  random
pygame.init()

class fruit:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=random.randint(0,size_y-1)
        self.y=random.randint(0,size_y-1)
        self.pos=Vector2(self.x,self.y)


    def draw_fruit(self):
        fruit_draw=pygame.Rect(self.pos.x*size_x,self.pos.y*size_x,size_x,size_x)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(200,150,160),fruit_draw)

size_x=30
size_y=25
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((size_y*size_x,size_y*size_x))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                quit()
    screen.fill(pygame.Color("dark green"))
    fruit().draw_fruit()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new fruit object every time loop does iteration.
You need to initialize it outside that loop. Also class names should be uppercase.

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.math import Vector2
import  random
pygame.init()

class Fruit:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=random.randint(0,size_y-1)
        self.y=random.randint(0,size_y-1)
        self.pos=Vector2(self.x,self.y)


    def draw_fruit(self):
        fruit_draw=pygame.Rect(self.pos.x*size_x,self.pos.y*size_x,size_x,size_x)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(200,150,160),fruit_draw)

size_x=30
size_y=25
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((size_y*size_x,size_y*size_x))

fruit = Fruit()  # fruit is now object,
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                quit()
    screen.fill(pygame.Color("dark green"))
    fruit.draw_fruit()  # drawing existing object.
    pygame.display.update()
```